# Weird log4j behaviour after upgrading from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 10

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, log4j2, java-17

I have upgraded to Tomcat 10 from Tomcat 8. Previously we created a folder "jars" inside the tomcat/lib folder and added them to the classpath on startup. This worked fine in Tomcat 8.

Since upgrading log4j has been a crap shoot of inconsistency.

Issue 1:

Add log4j jars to custom folder called "jars" inside tomcat/lib (%CATALINA_HOME/lib%) and use the startup script to add them to the classpath. If I do that I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem$1.filter(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:122)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger$PrivateConfig.filter(Logger.java:625)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.isEnabled(Logger.java:260)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper.isEnabled(ExtendedLoggerWrapper.java:93)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.isEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1476)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.ApiLogger.isLoggable(ApiLogger.java:85)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.isDebugEnabled(DirectJDKLog.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1244)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem$1.filter(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:122)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger$PrivateConfig.filter(Logger.java:625)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.isEnabled(Logger.java:260)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper.isEnabled(ExtendedLoggerWrapper.java:93)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.isEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1476)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.ApiLogger.isLoggable(ApiLogger.java:85)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.isDebugEnabled(DirectJDKLog.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1244)
```

Test 2:
Just add all the jars to the tomcat/lib folder and now we get the following exception (this makes the least amount of sense as the log4j-jul-2.20.0.jar file is clearly in the lib folder):

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:239)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:223)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:222)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.getLoggingProperty(SimpleFormatter.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.logger.SimpleConsoleLogger$Formatting.getSimpleFormat(SimpleConsoleLogger.java:505)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.logger.SurrogateLogger.getSimpleFormat(SurrogateLogger.java:62)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.<init>(SimpleFormatter.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<clinit>(DirectJDKLog.java:49)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
```

Issue 3 (This is by far the largest show stopper):

I can actually ignore "Issue 2" above and the application starts fine, but for a couple of my spring boot components the logging works initially but at some point during the application startup the logging just stops. There is no error anywhere and the application actually is running fine as I can access it but there are no log entries produced. Surely I am not the only one to encounter these issues since upgrading?

I have t say the move from Spring Boot 2.7.8, Tomcat 8 and JDK 11 to Spring Boot 3.0, Tomcat 10 and JDK 17 has been the most significantly painful I have ever had to do.

Comment: First, env var should be `%CATALINA_HOME%/lib`. Then, clean up log4j2* jars on tomcat and application path. Looks like a jar hell problem. Recommended: use a build/ dependecy manager instead of manually handling dependencies.

Comment: The catalina_home was a typo here, we have it configured correctly. We need to add the jars to the tomcat lib as we deploy custom security classes for loading tomcat certs. The log4j jars only live in 1 place and have done so for many iterations of our software. This is the first such issue.

We use maven for everything else. We have no duplicate jars in the webapp lib either.

Comment: You could try starting tomcat with `-verbose:class` and see if another log4j2 version is loaded first from maven dependencies

Comment: The exact versions of Spring Boot, Tomcat and the Log4j2 jars are useful to match your stack traces with the code. You general setup works fine for me.

Comment: I resolved issue 3 as that was an internal service setting log4j properties that was wiping out config due to it using obsolete calls.
I can workaround issue 1 by explicitly setting the classpath to my sub folder within the lib in a different place then before (previously we set it in the startup file I've now moved it to the common.loader declaration in catalina.properties).

Issue 2 still persists but causes no adverse effect on the application of it's logging. It's still bizarre and I'll have to do more digging into it to see why this is happening as the jul file is 100% on the classpath

Comment: Exact versions of everything is:

Tomcat 10.1.6, Java jdk-17.0.6+10, Spring Boot 3.0.4, Log4j 2.20.0

Comment: Do you intend to use log4j2 outside of your application (e.g. to configure Tomcat internal logging)? If not, then bundle your log4j2 libraries with the application and not with the server.

Comment: I also have this exact same issue. @user2028936 Did you manage to solve it? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I solved by setting the system property `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem` to `none`. The system property can be set as a catalina option (`CATALINA_OPTS`) but you can also set it from within the code in your implementation of [`SpringBootServletInitializer#configure`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/latest/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html#configure(org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder)) so it is always set whenever the application is run on an external container since the StackOverflowError only occurs when the app is deployed to an external Tomcat.

In the example below, the property is set when the application is running on an external container but only when log4j2-appserver is on the classpath or when the Log4J's JUL log manager is set.

```java
package my.dummy.project;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "my.dummy.project")
public class DummyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final String LOG4J_LOG_MANAGER = "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager";
    private static final boolean LOG4J_APPSERVER_PRESENT =
            ClassUtils.isPresent(
                    "org.apache.logging.log4j.appserver.tomcat.TomcatLogger",
                    PilotageApplication.class.getClassLoader());
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DummyApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder app) {
        if (LOG4J_APPSERVER_PRESENT || isLog4jLogManagerInstalled()) {
            System.setProperty(LoggingSystem.SYSTEM_PROPERTY, LoggingSystem.NONE);
        }
        
        return app.sources(DummyApplication.class);
    }
    
    private boolean isLog4jLogManagerInstalled() {
        return LOG4J_LOG_MANAGER.equals(
                java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by three facts:

1. If no logger context is associated with the current classloader, the default [`ContextSelector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/selector/ContextSelector.html) (`ClassLoaderContextSelector`) returns the logger context associated to a parent classloader. In this case the logger context associated with the system classloader.
2. During the initialization phase Spring Boot 3 adds a custom global filter to the logger context's configuration. This filter is a class from the webapp classloader.
3. Tomcat calls `Logger.isEnabled` in its classloader. The logger uses the logger context of the system classloader, which now has a filter from the webapp classloader, whose dependencies are not fully loaded. Therefore `Logger.isEnabled` causes an infinite loop, while trying to load [`Filter.Result`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x//javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Filter.Result.html).

I reported this as [Github issue #1430](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1430).

### Proper workaround

To workaround this problem you can:

1. Add [`log4j-jakarta-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jakarta-web) to your `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` folder (not the one with other Log4j 2.x libraries, this one also requires the Servlet API jars). This library will initialize Log4j 2.x before Spring Boot starts,
2. Add a servlet context parameter to your application's context configuration (e.g. in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`) with the location of your Log4j 2.x config file:

   ```xml
    <Parameter name="log4jConfiguration" value="/path/to/log4j2.xml"/>
   ```

By explicitly providing the path to your config file, the `ClassLoaderContextSelector` will create a new logger context for each application.

### Dirty workaround

A faster, but dirtier solution is to reference `Filter.Result` at an early stage of your application's startup:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter.Result", getClass().getClassLoader());
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```